# A-Frame tap to place

Tags: aframe, 8thwall-xr

Working with a-frame, can not find a way to create something similar to 8thWall´s [Cursor Place Ground](https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/placeground-cursor-aframe/code/body.html). I know [a-frame](https://aframe.io/) can support markerless AR, but I haven't been able to do it, so if anyone knows of any tutorials or hints on how to do markerless AR that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WebXRHitTest API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webxr-hit-test-1/) which is encapsulated in the [`ar-hit-test`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/ar-hit-test.html#sidebar) component.

With a setup like this:

```
<a-scene ar-hit-test="target:#my-objects;type:footprint;footprintDepth:0.2;">
   <a-entity id="my-objects">
      <a-box></a-box>
   </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

You can place the `#my-objects` entity by tapping on the floor - provided the surface was detected.

To provide some feedback, you can listen on the scene for these [events](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/ar-hit-test.html#events):

- `ar-hit-test-start` - when the system has started the scanning process
- `ar-hit-test-achieved` - when the surface was found
- `ar-hit-test-select` when the user tapped the screen to place an "anchor" with the items.

---

Resources:

- Ada Rose Cannon [tutorial](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/use-new-augmented-reality-features-with-just-a-few-lines-of-code-with-webxr-and-aframe-c6f3f5789345) - a must since she created the component
- Her [rollAR coaster](https://github.com/AdaRoseCannon/rollAR-coaster) creation app based on ar tapping
- My 'tap to move'... experiment? [tweet with video](https://mobile.twitter.com/gftru/status/1433228495677755396?cxt=HHwWiMC47aTu7OMnAAAA) ([ugly source code](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/cecfdb76333f849540239d92b6565f8331720fa2/aframe/ar/plane/ar.html))

Comment: This is not working for me... has something changed?

Comment: No idea, ill try to check it out this weekend